# Creating subplots in Bokeh with caption labels

Tags: python, bokeh

Sometimes in papers, you would like to create a figure with subplots which have labels *(a)*, *(b)*, etc.

How can you do this using [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html) and export the figure in `.png` format?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the (a) (b) labels, you can use subfigure library in latex, this will create the label for you.

You can export your fig to `png` format with the following code.

```
from bokeh.io import export_png

export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Creating subplots in Bokeh with caption labels, and exporting to `.png` format.

This code works for Bokeh version 2.0.0.

You might need to install the following to get `export_png` to work:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge selenium firefox geckodriver
```

see [the Bokeh docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html).

```py
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, export_png
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from PIL import Image

output_notebook()

x = list(range(100))

caption_text = ['(a)','(b)','(c)','(d)']
color = ['red','green','blue','orange']
f = [
    x,
    [a*a for a in x],
    [abs(a-len(x)/2) for a in x],
    [len(x)-a for a in x],
]

# There is a trade-off between figure resolution and png file size
plot_width = 400 # Make this larger for higher resolution
plot_height = 200 # Make this larger for higher resolution

fig = []
caption = []

for n in range(4):
    plt = figure(width=plot_width,
                 height=plot_height,
                )
    plt.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time (s)'
    plt.yaxis.axis_label = 'Power (W)'
    plt.line(x,f[n],color=color[n])
    fig.append(plt)

    # We make a simple plot for the captions
    plt = figure(width = plot_width,
                 height = 30, # Change to increase/decrease spacing
                )
    plt.add_layout(Label(
        x = plot_width/2-40, # Change to shift caption left or right
        y = 0, 
        x_units = 'screen',
        y_units = 'screen',
        text=caption_text[n],
        text_font = 'times', # Use same font as paper
        text_font_size = '12pt',
        text_align = 'center',
    ))
    plt.outline_line_color = None
    caption.append(plt)

# make a grid
grid = gridplot([fig[0], fig[1],
                 caption[0], caption[1],
                 fig[2], fig[3],
                 caption[2], caption[3],
                ],
                ncols=2,
               )

#show(grid)

png_file = "subplot_example.png"
export_png(grid, filename = png_file)

#Remove the bokeh toolbar (which is 32 pixels high)
im=Image.open(png_file)
width, height = im.size
im2=im.crop((0,32,width,height))
im2.save(png_file)
```

I cannot add the `.png` file that this creates, because I don't have enough reputation points.

Here is a [link though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRv8y.png).